# Rosparam fails silenntly with a wrong param?

Tags: ros, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I see the type of parameter I can pass to when I set a Rosparam?

I do

> $rosparam list

and got:

> /background_r
>
> /background_g
>
> /background_b

etc

those are intuitive enough to predict that are ints

but if i need the type by doing

> $rosparam type /background_r

I got an error since that command is not existing...

on the other hand, doing:

> $rosparam set /background_r "foo"

fails silently...

what am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257797/rosparam-fails-silenntly-with-a-wrong-param?/) by [LbrRobix](https://answers.ros.org/users/29792/lbrrobix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually Ros has a parameter server that is nothing else as a Dictionary,
parameter there has not type as you are specting...

so to the question: when you do:

$rosparam set /background_r "foo"

How you now it is failing? is not actually, you just wrote the parameter **/background_r** to **"foo"** in the dictionary

you can verify that by getting the value: just do:

$rosparam get /background_r

and you will get **foo**

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0